# Data Exchange Framework delete records in Sitecore if does not Exist in Source(CRM)

Tags: pipelines, data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

Just noticed the behavior of Data Exchange Framework that it does not delete the records that is already created in Sitecore upon Synchronization and run Sync again after deleting a record in CRM. Is this something that need to be done as a custom provider? Or is there already an out of the box pipeline on Data Exchange Framework ready for Synchronizing Deleted records.

Comment: what entity from CRM  you want to syncronize?  What CRM are you using ?

Comment: I am using the "account" entity.

Comment: and you create items on Sitecore or contacts in xDB?

Comment: I created the items in Sitecore. Mapped into one of my Template.

Comment: Do you have an identifier in your account object?

Comment: Yes I do have an identifier in my account object.

Comment: My Identifier is the accountid in CRM.

Comment: A few additional questions: Which CRM are using? Dynamics CRM?
During a synchronization do you get all objects from CRM or just updated entries?

Comment: I am using Dynamics CRM. During Sync I do get all the objects from CRM.

Comment: Is the issue still actual?

Comment: Yes. Already confirmed with Sitecore that the deletion functionality of non existent records that are already created in Sitecore and was deleted in CRM is needed to be created on our own customization as the OOTB does not support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Dynamics CRM cannot send request to Sitecore to notify that entity was deleted. You can add a custom solution like "Clean Up Sync" pipeline batch to send a request to determine whether Dynamics Crm Entity exists by Sitecore record Id, if no remove record.

---

**Option 1**

Read Sitecore Records Pipeline:

1. Get All Sitecore Records Step
2. Iterate Step -> [Clean Up Records Pipeline]

Clean Up Records Pipeline:

1. Find Dynamics Entity By Record Id Step
2. Remove Sitecore Record if not found Step

**Option 2**

Read Sitecore Records Pipeline:

1. Create Queue Step
2. Get All Sitecore Records Step
3. Iterate Step -> [Resolve Records Pipeline]
4. Remove Bulk Records in Queue Step

Resolve Records Pipeline:

1. Find Dynamics Entity By Record Id Step
2. Add Record to the Queue If Not Found Step

---

Follow this example you can add one more Clean Up Sync but for the records which were removed from Sitecore.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Vlad Sphak. I did the option 1 you've mentioned in my problem. Thanks a lot. :)